# Object creation for two different classes throws StackOverflow in java

Tags: java, swing

I have been struggling with this problem for a while where I have two classes namely `OrderSearch.java`(main class) and `CreateOrder.java`. I have a `JTable` on my main `class` and when a row is doubleclicked it opens a new frame i.e `CreateOrder.java` with values from `jTable`in different textfields. I have a `SaveButton` in CreateOrder.java that saves the changes made in the class and shows it `JTable` again.

However the problem is I cannot perform refresh table operation i.e some sql queries when the SaveButton is clicked. I want the table in frame OrderSearch is refreshed when the savebutton on CreateOrder is clicked

Problems: Creating an object for class OrderSearch.java in CreateOrder.java gives me a stackoverflow error. Creating an object in the Savebutton opens a whole new frame again.

OrderSearch.java

```
public class OrderSearch extends CreateOrder{ 
//declarations for label,text, and buttons


public static void main(String[] args) {

       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                OrderSearch window = new OrderSearch();
                window.frmXraymanager.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

   public OrderSearch () {        *Stack overflow error here*
    initialize();
    }

private void initialize() {

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e2) {

            if (e2.getClickCount() == 2 && !e2.isConsumed())   {
                 e2.consume();
            try{
            int index = table.getSelectedRow();

            String table_Click = table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(index), 0).toString();


            String sql = "SELECT ID, Date, Place, UserName FROM TEST.dbo.Intern WHERE ID = '"+table_Click+"'";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
            String id = rs.getString("ID");
            String date = rs.getString("Date").toString();
            String place = rs.getString("Place");
            String uname = rs.getString("UserName");

        frameCreate.setVisible(true);  //Frame from CreateOrder.java

        Number.setText(id); // textfields from CreateOrder.java
        String date1 = startDate;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        Date date2 = df.parse(date1);

        dateChooser.setDate(date2);
        jobSite.setText(place);
        uName.setText(uname);
        Component.setText(component);
        Remarks.setText(remarks);
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
            }
        }
    });
   }

    public void refresh()
       {
                query1 = "SELECT * FROM Test.dbo.Intern;


            try(PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();){



            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            table.setRowHeight(40);

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

CreateOrder.java

```
public class CreateOrder {

   public CreateOrder () {
    initialize();
    }
 OrderSearch one = new OrderSearch();   *Stack overflow error here*    

private void initialize() {

button_Save = new JButton("Save");
    button_Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            *would like to add refresh() here*

        }
    });

}
}
```

How should I create an object of OrderSearch in CreateOrder to acces the method `refresh()` without opening the frame again?

Thanks in advance!

-Ajay

EDIT:

Actually the error is in

```
OrderSearch one = new OrderSearch();
```

and public `OrderSearch ()` I totally understand it makes sense because it goes into infinite loop when I call an Object in CreateOrder.java. But is there any way to access the contents of OrderSearch.java in CreateOrder.java without getting the stackoverflow error or opening the whole new frame OrderSearch.java again?

Comment: maybe refactor your code so that the SQL is in a separate class that can be called

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for your reply. But what about the jTable?
I mean if I create a class 'refresh extends OrderSearch{ }' its gonna give me again stackoverflow error. Sorry I am a newby in java

Comment: why do you want to extend `OrderSearch`  In my mind this refactored code should be able to standalone regardless of what you are connecting it to.  Loosely coupled code is the aim

Comment: Which methods are forming the infinite cycle?

Comment: how do i get table from OrderSearch in new class? I mean its clear that I have to create an object for the main class in new class in order to access table? Or could you please provide me with an example about your method. I'd be really grateful

Comment: @LajosArpad when I declare `OrderSearch one = new OrderSearch();` in `Public Class CreateOrder()` it always shows stackoverflow error in `public CreateOrder ()`

Comment: That line is not in your question.

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry for the inconvienience I copied the working code. Actually the error is in `OrderSearch one = new OrderSearch();` and `public OrderSearch ()` 
I totally understand it makes sense because it goes into infinite loop when I call an Object in `CreateOrder.java`. But is there any way to access the contents of `OrderSearch.java` in `CreateOrder.java` without getting the stackoverflow error or opening the whole new frame `OrderSearch.java` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it assuming your current setup. This leads us to the conclusion that you need to refactor the code. The main problem is that your code has no way to execute the required db command without creating a frame. You will need to [separate the engine from the ui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127245/how-can-i-separate-the-user-interface-from-the-business-logic-while-still-mainta). You will need to be able to execute business logic without being tied to a UI event. The UI should be a user of the business logic, not its wrapper. You will need to move all your business logic into separate class(es) and call the relevant methods from the ui at the appropriate places and events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. It seems lot of work but I hope the link you provided helps.

Comment: @Ajay you are welcome! The basic idea is that you need to organize your code, so that you eliminate all unnecessary dependencies. You will have necessary dependencies, but unnecessary dependencies make your work very difficult. If you get a grasp of this concept, suddenly everything will be much easier.